# Browser crash after adding dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

After i was adding an extra dependency in my module, the whole thing just crashed in the browser (unable to do anything).

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAppRename due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAppRename.view2 due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMessages due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMessages' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

It was after adding ng-message to my module, but it seems like it is a generally problem with all kinds of dependencies.

This is what my module looks like:

```
angular.module('myAppRename.view2', ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages'])
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: did you include the script? angular-messages.js?

Comment: can you please give the entire code in your app.js?.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same problem and the error was that I had forgotten to add the angular-messages script to my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```